# Cannot find OpenCV 3.3.1 Extra Modules for Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, module, face-recognition

When I try to download OpenCV 3.3.1 from https://opencv.org/releases/page/4/ for Android, only the main modules are present even though the documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/) says that it includes the extra modules. My target module is FaceRecognizer. Is there any way to get this module elsewhere?

Comment: Extra modules are part of opencv_contrib repository: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules

Comment: Will they work for Android (java)? Because I see .cpp files inside the face folder. And how do I include them into my android project?

Comment: I have successfully added one extra module in kivy for android app. Not sure about android project. You can try to copy the concerned module in the normal module directory and modify the relevant entries like list of generated module names (which was the case for kivy for android app case).

Comment: Those did not work, they contain c++ files not .java

Comment: I am searching for opencv_contrib with java support.